# while loop for user input doesn't exit

Tags: python

The code I have below isn't stopping when I enter the `exitCode`, and the other problem is that the `elif` line is detecting every character entered as a number.

```
counter = 0
exitCode = 'X'
wantsToExit = False

while counter < 6 and wantsToExit == False:
        candyName = str(input('Enter the candy\'s code/name ({0} to exit): '.format(exitCode)))
        if candyName == "{0}".format(exitCode):
            wantsToExit == True
            print("You have chosen to exit.")
        elif candyName.isdigit:
            print("Please only enter letters.")
```

Comment: Try to make Your title more explanatory. What pyton version do You use? I guess that 3.x

Comment: It is the latest version of Python.

Comment: `str.isdigit()` is function, You have to type it with `()`.  
"{0}".format(exitCode) makes string that in place of {0} put exitCode. Just use `if candyName == exitCode`
`==` means "is left equal to right?' but You want to change it's value. Use `=` instead.

Comment: Thank you @Dzarafara, that solved it. That was a noobie mistake for sure.. Does anybody have a solution to the X problem? It just repeats the input question after the exit message.

Comment: See my updated answer below

Comment: It's a Good Idea to tag your questions with the Python version you're using. As I mention below, there are important differences between Python 2.x and Python 3.x in the way the input() function works.

Comment: Also, please don't put stuff like "Please help me quick, this is important!" in your questions. Having that stuff in your question probably earned you a few downvotes. Try to write your questions so that they'll not only help you, but will also be helpful to future readers. To make your question most useful to others it's good if you can isolate your problems so each question focuses on one problem; if you have 2 problems, write 2 questions. Of course, sometimes it's not easy to isolate problems like that, but you'll get a better response here if you try to make that effort.

Answer (score 4):

There are several problems with your code.

As Dzarafata mentioned,

1. you are testing the value of `counter` at the top of your `while` loop but you never change its value in the loop.
2. `elif candyName.isdigit:` *doesn't* test if the string `candyName` only consists of digits. To do that, you need to actually *call* the method, like this: `elif candyName.isdigit()`.
   However, this is probably not the test you really want, since it doesn't catch strings that contain non-letters that aren't digits, eg, punctuation marks.

FWIW, `if candyName.isdigit:` tests the truth value of the `candyName.isdigit` method itself. In Python a method is an object and any object that isn't equivalent to `0`, `False`, `None`, or some other null object like an empty string, list, tuple, set, dict, etc, is considered to be `True`. So

```
if candyName.isdigit:
    print("stuff")
```

will *always* print `stuff`, no matter what string is in candyName.

A 3rd problem with your code is that it doesn't exit from the `while` loop when it gets correct data.

A minor flaw in your code is `str(input(stuff))`. The Python 3 `input()` function *always* returns a string, so there's no need to convert its output to string with `str()`. But if you're using Python 2 then you should avoid using `input()` and use `raw_input()` instead, as the Python 2 `input()` can do dangerous things with untrusted input.

Here's a modified version of your code. I've changed `candyName` to `candy_name` to comply with the usual Python naming convention. I've modified the logic to use `break` statements, so we no longer need the `wantsToExit` flag.

```
exitCode = 'X'
prompt = "Enter the candy's code/name ({0} to exit): ".format(exitCode)

#Make upto 6 attempts to get correct input
candy_name = None
for counter in range(1, 7):
    data = input("{0}: {1}".format(counter, prompt))
    if data == exitCode:
        print("You have chosen to exit.")
        break
    elif not data.isalpha():
        print("Please only enter letters.")
    else:
        candy_name = data
        break

if candy_name is None:
    print("No valid candy name was entered")
else:
   print("Candy name: '{0}'".format(candy_name))
```

Note that I use `data` to store the user input string, and I only copy it to `candy_name` once we've made sure it's a valid name. This version also prints the current value of `counter` at the start of the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Change those lines:

```
wantsToExit == True
elif candyName.isdigit:
```

to:

```
wantsToExit = True
elif candyName.isdigit():
```

Also: Your loop is going until counter is < 6 so You have to make it bigger in each iteration by doing `counter += 1`

Answer (score 0):

Correct this lines:

```
 wantsToExit == True
 elif candyName.isdigit:
```

To this:

```
 wantsToExit = True
 elif candyName.isdigit():
```